Visual Studio solution associated with multiple git repositories, but needs to be only one
On the bottom right hand side in Visual Studio it says my solution, which contains one project, is associated with two git repositories:

One is the correct one, and one is a repository for a different solution. How do I disconnect the repository that is from a different solution?
There is a bunch of stuff I tried to resolve this, which resulted in loosing one year of code, were it not that I made a backup. It's confusing me.

By having your solution, and all its related projects, inside a single git repo?

I used the term 'project' where I should have used 'solution'. I edited my post to fix that mistake. As for your comment, not sure what you mean. I don't understand why it is not in a single repo. Somehow it is in two.
